# Attempting to run three domains on VPS, one works, the other two show apache test page

Tags: apache, multiple-domains

I have three domains that I'm pointing at one VPS.

One resides in /www/html/ while the other two have their own folder inside of /www/html/. The first of my domains works fine.

The other two, however, only land at the **apache** test page. I've commented out everything in conf.d/welcome.conf, yet I still get the test page.

**Here's what I've got for httpd.conf**

```
<VirtualHost 192.241.117.214:80>
ServerName tishu.org
ServerAlias www.tishu.org
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.241.117.2:80>
ServerName avrse.net
ServerAlias www.avrse.net
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/avrse
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.241.117.3:80>
ServerName pureavarice.com
ServerAlias www.pureavarice.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/vera
</VirtualHost>
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: After editing your server's `httpd.conf` did you restart Apache?

Comment: Yes, I've restarted Apache a few times.

Comment: What's the user and group associated with those directories? If you change it so that the working one uses a different domain and documentroot, does it then work?

Comment: If I switch the documentroot for tishu.org to /avrse it properly displays my index file and other directories insdie of avrse, like how avrse.net should be working. I'm not sure how to answer your first question though, I just started learning this stuff yesterday, so I'm still a little green.

Comment: Alright, I figured it out. I was pointing my other domains at 192.241.117.2 and .3, where I should have just had the regular IP in there. I was following bad directions it seems.